# How to start a service on startup on Debian headless server (Raspberry Pi)?

Tags: linux, boot, raspberry-pi, autostart

I would like to start aria2 as a daemon on startup on Raspberry Pi headless server (no GUI, just SSH access)

I created a **service aria2cRPC** that starts the application (got help from: http://www.megaleecher.net/Raspberry_Pi_Autostart)
It starts the app like this:

```
sudo aria2c --daemon --enable-rpc --rpc-listen-all
```

When I start the service from SSH console

```
sudo service aria2cRPC start
```

Everythink works as expected.

But when I add the service to autostart on boot, it won't start.

```
sudo update-rc.d aria2cRPC defaults
```

Should I change the runlevel? Which level should I use? How can I test that the service is at least trying to start on boot?

EDIT: When I look into **/etc/rcX.d** I can see my service at:

```
/etc/rc0.d K01aria2cRPC
/etc/rc1.d K01aria2cRPC
/etc/rc2.d S01aria2cRPC
/etc/rc3.d S01aria2cRPC
/etc/rc4.d S01aria2cRPC
/etc/rc5.d S01aria2cRPC
/etc/rc6.d K01aria2cRPC
```

Does it mean that the service should be running when booted without X (run level 2,3,4)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to create a blank txt file which path is specified in aria2 config: **input-file**.

Aria2 is not able to handle the situation when there is some file path specified, but it doesn't exist. So it won't start. But also doesn't display any error which is quite tricky.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the default run level for the Raspberry Pi is 2, so the default settings should be OK.  You can check if that's indeed the case by invoking `who -r`.

The sequence number that you used (`01`) is quite low.  This could be reason enough for the service not to start, if it depends on other services that have higher sequence numbers.  I suggest that you try again with a higher one, e.g.

```
sudo update-rc.d aria2cRPC defaults 99
```

after removing the links.

> Should I change the runlevel? Which level should I use?

You don't have to change your run level, unless you have other reasons for doing so.

> How can I test that the service is at least trying to start on boot?

You can add a line like the following to your `/etc/init.d/aria2cRPC` script:

```
echo "`/bin/date` $1" >> /var/tmp/aria-rc.log
```

which will log all of your script invocations. (`$1` will be the script's first parameter, `start` or `stop`).

Comment: Ok, so I've checked with `runlevel` and it is level 2. I renamed the file to `/etc/rc2.d S90aria2cRPC` (using `mv`). I was thinking maybe there is a problem with running `sudo` in the shell script, so I added a line at the very end of `sudo visudo`: 
`pi ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/aria2c`
But it won't help.. any other ideas?

Comment: Of course you have checked that the target of your links (your `/etc/init.d/aria2cRPC` script) is owned by `root:root` and has permissions `755`.

Comment: I added the `echo` line just next to the aria2c line and the script is starting on boot. So the problem must be with calling the application.

The script is owned by root and has permission 777. Is it ok? What about the application (also root and 755) - should I modify the ownership or permissions?

Comment: It may not be the cause of the problem but you should fix the permissions.  You'll need to debug your script and I don't think I can help much without being able to put my hands on it.

Comment: OK, how should I fix those? I mean I have no problem Googling commands, but I don't know to what should I set those? Like 755 on every file/script? Should all of them be owned by user pi?

The script is the same as the script it step 3 here: http://www.megaleecher.net/Raspberry_Pi_Autostart
But the line starting the application (nohup ... ) is like the one in my question - I changed it because the line didn't start aria2c daemon even from SSH..